# How many objects were created where B is inherited from A?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Here are two classes,

```
class A
{
}
class B extends A
{
}
```

and **A** is inherited from **B**.What confuses me is that How many objects were created when I use the following code

```
A a =  new B();
```

I know when I create an instance of **B** ,it will first call **A**'s constructor and then call the constructor of **B**'s.
Was there an instance of **A** been created when call **A**'s constructor?
How many objects were created in

```
A a = new B();
```

Comment: Constructor does not create the object. It is a method that runs on an object that was already created by the JVM.

Comment: For each `new`, there's one object constructed.

Comment: Yes, it's a plain method that runs on your object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It creates a single object, which is an instance of `B`. It's already a `B` when the `A` constructor executes, as you'll see if you change your code to:

```
class A {
    public A() {
        System.out.println(getClass());
    }
}

class B extends A {
}

...

A a = new B(); // Prints B in the A constructor
```

Basically, the constructor isn't what *creates* an object - it's what *initializes* an object in the context of that class.

So you can think of the steps as:

- Create object of type B
- Initialize the object in the context of A (field initializers, constructor body)
- Initialize the object in the context of B (field initializers, constructor body)

(with constructor chaining *up* the inheritance tree evaluating constructor arguments, of course... while the constructors are sort-of called going up the chain too, as the *first* part of any constructor has to chain to the same class or a superclass, the main part of the constructor body happens top-down).

For rather more detail about *exactly* what happens, see [JLS 15.9.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4) and [JLS 12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5).

Comment: Can I think of the constructor as a common method, it's only used to initialize the fields and is invoked by the object ?

Comment: @RubingYang: Sort of. Except you can't invoke it directly, and it has special rules. (It can do things other than initialize fields, of course - it just usually doesn't.)

Answer (score 3):

**One** object is created, which is a `B` object, which has both the aspects defined by `A` and the aspects defined by `B`. Since it incorporates all of the aspects defined by both of them, it's `instanceof` both `A` and `B`.

> ...and `A` is inherited from `B`

`A` is inherited *by* `B`, not *from* it. (The little words are the hardest in a non-native language.) `B` inherits *from* `A`. Some usual terms around this: "`B` derives from `A`", "`B` is derived from `A`", "`A` is a superclass of `B`", "`B` is a subclass of `A`".

> Was there an instance of `A` been created when call `A`'s constructor?

Despite their name, constructors don't create objects; they *initialize* them; and this question is why: Sometimes to correctly initialize the object, you have to call multiple constructors (one for each level in the object's inheritance hierarchy). In `new B()`, the JVM creates the object, then calls `B` with `this` set to that new, blank object so `B` can initialize it. The first thing `B` does is call `A` to let it initialize the `A` aspects of the object, then `B` initializes the `B` aspects of the object. E.g.:

1. JVM creates object.
2. JVM calls `B`
3. `B` calls `A`
4. `A` initializes the aspects of the object it's responsible for and returns
5. `B` initializes the aspects of the object it's responsible for and returns

Comment: @RubingYang: That's what I meant by "The little words are the hardest in a non-native language." :-)

Comment: `Despite their name, constructors don't create objects; they initialize them`  That was awesome for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Only one instance of `B` is created.

Constructors can be called up the chain, but each call only acts on the single instance that you're creating.

Answer (score 0):

As those above me already said: Only one object is created. To clarify this you might think of the three parts of the statement you just wrote down: 
`A a = new B()`. These are the part of declaration `A a`, the part of instantiation `new` and the part of initialization `B()`.

If you want to read up on this topic (because perhaps not everything got clear to you), consider visiting https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html